# Can't setup Server Farm on IIS for YouTrack

Tags: iis, windows-server-2008-r2, issue-tracking, youtrack

I have Windows Server and IIS. I have a main domain site.com, and I want to setup my issue tracker here - bugs.site.com. I have installed youtrack on my Windows Server. Then I have created Server Farm on IIS and created on virtual Server (take a look at the picture below).

[image]

My issue is that once I visit bugs.site.com, I will see the main site BUT without any styles.

How can I resolve my issue?